# iOS keyboard glitches all animations

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, keyboard

I have a View Controller dedicated to login process. It has 2 separate views for 2 stages of the process. Sadly I'm not allowed to post images, it would've been easier to explain.

There's animation process that hides first view and shows second view. It starts with a press of a button. On the second view (which appears only after transition animations) there's a textfield. Everything works fine until keyboard shows up.

I dismiss keyboard with this code if user pressed anywhere on the screen

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
[self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

If Keyboard has ever appeared on the screen and was dismissed - back animations are glitched. My current view disappears, but the other one never shows up. If you don't touch the keyboard everything works fine. Animations are pretty straightforward

```
[UIView animateWithDuration]
```

I make one view invisible and the other one moves to/from the side of the screen.

Has anyone had the similar issue? Any idea  why this is happening? How can I look for possible reasons?

**UPDATE:**

Animation code:

```
- (IBAction)backButtonPressed:(id)sender {

//prepare for animations
// [self.view endEditing:YES];


[UIView animateWithDuration:kHIDE_ANIMATION_DURATION
                 animations:^{

                     //hide current view
                     _loginView.alpha = 0;


                     //waves animation
                     //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                     [UIView animateWithDuration:kWAVES_ANIMATION_DURATION
                                           delay:0
                          usingSpringWithDamping:1
                           initialSpringVelocity:0
                                         options:UIViewAnimationOptionOverrideInheritedDuration
                                      animations:^{

                                          CGPoint center = _waves.center;
                                          center.y -= _waves.frame.size.height/4;
                                          _waves.center = center;

                                      }
                                      completion:nil];
                     //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){

                     NSLog(@"Back_Button_Starts_Complition_Block");
                     [UIView animateWithDuration:kMOVE_ANIMATION_DURATION
                                      animations:^{

                          //clean up
                         _loginView.hidden = YES;

                         //show next view
                         CGPoint center = _welcomeView.center;
                         center.x += self.view.bounds.size.width;
                         _welcomeView.center = center;

                     }];


                 }];

}
```

**UPDATE 2:**

I have an idea what might be causing the problem. I use autolayout in this scene.It seems like when keyboard shows up autolayout updates position of the moved view.

Everything inside this movable view (_welcomeView) is positioned with autolayout. I could have positioned _welcomeView with code but if I delete constraints for this _welcomeView it will mess up autolayout for all its subviews.

The only way to solve this issue that comes to my mind is to move _welcomeView back after animation is completed and while its invisible. But it sounds like a terrible design. Any ideas?

Comment: can you please edit your post with the code related to the animation.. you can upload the screenshot to imgur.com for the time being.

Comment: I updated my post with animation code. This is backwards animation, I do the exact opposite animation when moving to this view that has textfield. I would think that I messed up animation somehow, but it works as intended if you don't touch textfield.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I confirm that origin of the problem was in autolayout. The view that I was moving with animation was placed inside superview with constraints. It appears that when keyboard is about to show up (or did show up, not sure when exactly) *-layoutIfNeeded/-layoutSubviews* is called and frames updates to match their constraints. My loginView was moved away with no change to its constraints, so it was brought back whenever keyboard is called, but my animation code was still considering this view as moved off the screen. I hope this will clear up same problem for someone someday and help save some time.

The proper way is to update (remove/add new) constraints if you move something and use autolayout. Or you could have originally positioned your view with *-initWithFrame:*